# Discrete Math number of multiplications it takes to calculate $x^{15}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, discrete-optimization

This is in the topic of time complexity and algorithms in my list of problems and I really wanted to figure it out how to take a grip.

Here's the problem:

Find the number of multiplications needed to calculate $x^{15}$ as:

- $((x^2)^2 \cdot x)^3$
- $((x^2)^2)^2 \cdot(x^2)^2 \cdot x^2 \cdot x$

Can I use some math magic to solve even first problem and then get going for any one like that? Or do I have to simplify them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t want to simplify them: you want to count the multiplications required in order to calculate $x^{15}$ in each of those two ways. Assuming that you store intermediate results, so that you don’t have to recalculate them, the second approach takes $6$ multiplications:

- one to get $x\cdot x=x^2$;
- one to get $x^2\cdot x^2=(x^2)^2$;
- one to get $(x^2)^2\cdot(x^2)^2=\big((x^2)^2\big)^2$
- one to get $\big((x^2)^2\big)^2\cdot(x^2)^2$;
- one to multiply that by $x^2$; and
- one to multiply that by $x$.

Now can you count the multiplications required if you organize the calculation as $\big((x^2)^2\cdot x\big)^3$?

Comment: Oh I think it takes 4 multiplications for the first one. Am I right? One for $x^2$ one for $(x^2)^2$ another for $(x^2)^2 * x$ and finally the cube?

Comment: @ideaot: Not quite: the cubing takes two multiplications, so you need $5$ altogether.

Comment: I got it now thanks! I'll do some more examples.

Comment: @ideaot: You’re welcome!